# "Developer error: this application is misconfigured" Google sign in on firebase with whitelisted client id

Tags: android, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to migrate to firebase auth on my android app. The package name and SHA1 are currently associated with an old app engine project (which I don't want to upgrade to firebase) and therefore I can't add the SHA1 fingerprint to my new firebase project. The app engine project is currently in production, so I can't remove the android client ids or delete the project. The documentation here https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?authuser=0 says that I should be able to whitelist the client IDs of the old app engine project. However when I do this and then try to log in to the app with google using firebase auth I get the following error `"Developer error: this application is misconfigured. Check your SHA1 and package name in the Firebase console."`

I have also tried the instructions here https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html which involve passing in a `GoogleSignInOptions`object into the AuthUI builder with a web client id from the appropriate project like so:

```
private void StartLoginActivity() {

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("<my-client-id>.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().setSignInOptions(gso).build());

    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

but when I do that I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: two different server client ids provided`

So my question is how can I configure my firebase project to enable auth when the SHA1 is associated with an existing GCP project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the following response from firebase support and was able to get this working:

> Google sign in with FirebaseUI is configured through the google-services.json >file. The issue is that if you are using an OAuth client ID from a different >project, the default_web_client_id will be configured incorrectly. It will be >pointing to the auto generated web client id of your new Firebase project; we >don't want this.
>
> In step 1 of https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend->auth, we call #requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id)). In >firebaseUI, this is also done and this resource is 'default_web_client_id' - >generated by google-services.json. This needs to be changed.
>
> So to resolve the issue you need to use the web OAuth client ID from project >#1, you can do this by either:
>
> Changing the google-services.json file - you'd need to change the client_id >fields to the correct web client id from project #1
>   You also need to whitelist (Auth > Sign In Providers > Google) the web client >OAuth from project#1 to project#2
>
> Not use google-services.json so you can set the default_web_client_id himself. We made a guide for this, see [here](https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4).

Here's the process I followed to get this working:

1. Go to GCP Console > Select old project > Apis and services > Credentials
2. Create credentials > OAuth client ID
3. Select *Web application*

   - Enter a name
   - Leave Javascript origins and authorized redirect URLS blank
4. Copy the client id
5. Open firebase console
6. Go to authentication > sign-in method > google
7. Whitelist the new client id > add > save
8. Go back to settings > add firebase to your android app

   - Add your android package name
   - Leave signing certificate empty
9. Click register app
10. Download & open google-services.json
11. In oauth_client there will be an entry for each oauth client id in your app (FYI these can be seen on the GCP console under Apis and services > Credentials).
12. Delete the whole `oauth_client` tag and replace with

      `"oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "<your_new_client_id>",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],`

    If you need any of the other oauth clients then make sure that the whitelisted one is at the top as this seems to be the default.
13. Save the file & copy into your android app module.
14. Make sure you have the following dependencies:

    - project root build.gradle
    - classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    - app module build.gradle
    - compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    - compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
15. Build & Run your project

If you get this error (with no futher details): 

 `BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyBJL6EO8vMEJpyWUCAKP8ZgH4LYR0Hrwpk`

Check your gradle dependendies are set to the versions above (or higher)

If you get this error: 

`com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Invalid Idp Response:the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application. Its audience (OAuth 2.0 client ID) is <your-client-id>, which is not authorized to be used in the project with project_number: <your-project-number>. ]`

Try removing & re-adding your whitelisted client id on the firebase console.

Comment: Lifesaver! The Firebase support sent me here. Quick tip if you get error Code 10 from FirebaseUI: Change something in your gradle config (add an empty line for example), Gradle Sync, uninstall app, rebuild, run.

Comment: I did these steps and got Google Sign in to work. I have an existing project in Google Cloud Console which had the same package name + SHA1. I am now trying to enable Phone Sign In and it seems like I need to add SHA1 to the firebase project which I cannot do for the same reason (already exists). Is there a special step to allow Phone Sign In?